# Win32 Superclassing Initialization Problems

Tags: winapi, superclass

So I am working on making my own wrapper class that can quickly and easily produce both custom (user defined) windows and provided (system defined) windows and allows for a custom WndProc for each. I have it set up fine aside from trying to super class the button class. I have tried several different iterations of trying to set up the super class (in terms of what I am setting to NULL and what I am redefining in the WNDCLASSEX) but no matter what I do, when it goes to register the new class I have defined in the WNDCLASSEX structure, it tells me "Error the parameter is incorrect." I tried switching to a basic Win32 project that creates just creates a blank window to see if I could implement the super classing technique in there but the error persists and I have no idea why. The relevant code is:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory( &wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) );
    GetClassInfoEx( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), L"Button", &wc );
    SetOldProc( (LONG_PTR)wc.lpfnWndProc );
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myButton";
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = AbstractWindow::msgRouter;
    if ( !RegisterClassEx( &wc ) )
    {
         ::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,        
                 NULL,                                      
                 GetLastError(),                            
                 MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
              lpBuffer,                                 
                 sizeof(lpBuffer)-1,                        
                 NULL);
         MessageBox (NULL, lpBuffer, L"Button", MB_ICONERROR) ;
         return 0 ;
    }
```

The SetOldProc is a method within the wrapper class I am making that stores the pointer to the original button WndProc and the AbstractWindow::msgRouter is the WndProc in the base class for my wrapper class that routes messages to the correct window classes when they are received. Custom classes within the wrapper classes work just fine the way the wrapper classes are set up and like I said, I have tried multiple variations of what variables in the WNDCLASSEX structure I change, including only giving it a name and instance, but everything I try just gives me the same error even if it is in a bare bones project and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Corrections to the code, tips for super classing, etc. are all welcome even if it isn't directly relevant to fixing my problem because I always like to learn more but if you have a solution please share it.

Comment: You're not setting up your WNDCLASSEX correctly, and ignoring the return value of `GetClassInfoEx`, which is returning FALSE. You never set the `cbSize` member of your `wc` object before invoking `GetClassInfoEx`, and thus it fails. You assume it succeeded, then perform the remainder of your setup (all while still ignoring that very-important member), then try to register a quite-broken `wc`. See [the documentation for `WNDCLASSEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx), and in particular, the *second* sentence of the `cbSize` member text.

Comment: @WhozCraig: this should be posted as an answer, not a comment.